# Filter logic using through associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have `Bike` and `Category` models. Bike has_many categories through `BikeFilter` model.

The problem is, that from search for I get let's say 5 different categories and I need to find only these bikes, which has all 5 of these categories records in `BikeFilter` table.

If I do GROUP BY in mysql, it selects also records, who has only 1 or few categories in `bike_filters`. And need who has only all of them.

Bike.rb

```
has_many :bike_filters
has_many :categories, :through => :bike_filters
```

BikeFilter.rb

```
belongs_to :category
belongs_to :bike
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `having` clause:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#having

And do something like the following:

```
Bike.select("bikes.*, count(*) as num_of_categories")
  .joins(:categories)
  .where(categories: { id: cats })
  .group("bikes.id")
  .having("num_of_categories = ?", cats.length)
```

This query will first perfom an Inner Join between the Bikes and Categories (via the BikeFilter table), then it will select only rows where the category_id is included in the `cats` array. 
At this points the query will group all records according to the bike id and return only groups with a number of rows equal to the number of categories.

Couple of notes:

- This will only work if the (bike_id, category_id) pair is unique in the BikeFilter table.
- This query will return all bikes associated with all given categories, regardless of whether they have other catagories associated with them or not.

Comment: However, if `cats`contains e.g. 5 categories, this does not only deliver those bikes that have **all 5** categories. You also get bikes having 5 categories with only one of them belonging to `cats`.

Comment: @tillmo - I don't think so - filtering only rows with category id in `cats` (the where clause) filters all rows so the only remaining rows are bikes with category in `cats` so other categories would not be counted upon on `count(*)` and thus not considered.

Comment: you are right. However, `>=` versus `=` makes no difference. In both cases, all bikes including the specified categories are returned. This is because `where(categories: { id: cats })` already restricts counting to the specified categories.